Bound with expectation of minimum
Let $B(n,p)$ a binomial random variable. I want to show
$$\max_{p}  \left\{2 \cdot\mathbb E_{X \sim B(n,p)}[\min \{n-k, X\}] - n p (1+p) \right\} \geq \frac{n - k}{4}$$
for any $k \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$.
What I have right now;
I know that the left-hand side is maximized by $p^*$ that fulfills the following equation
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb P_{X \sim B(n-1,p^*)}(X \geq n- k) = \frac{1-2p^*}{2}.
\end{equation*}
Furthermore, one can show that
\begin{align*}2 \cdot\mathbb E_{X \sim B(n,p)}[\min \{n-k, X\}] - n p (1+p) &= 2(n-k) \cdot \mathbb P_{X \sim B(n,p)}(X \geq n-k+1)\\ & \quad+ 2 np \cdot \mathbb P_{X \sim B(n-1,p)}(X \leq n - k - 1)   \\ & - np(1+p)
\end{align*}
and after a little bit of algebra, plugging $p^*$ in the above leads to
$$ (n-k)(1-2p^*)  + n {p^*}^{2} - (n-k)(1-p^*)\mathbb P_{X \sim B(n-1,p)}(X = n-k),$$
but I have no clue in order to show what I want from here.
Update:
I was wondering if one could do the following argument; we know that for $k \in \{0, n\}$, we have trivial solutions (respectively $p = 1/2$ and $p=0$). So it would only suffice to show that the LHS function is -discrete- concave in $k$.
I have tried to show this, but it seems difficult. Instead, consider the continuous extension to $k \in [0, n]$ and approximate the binomial distribution by a continuous random variable with cdf $F$, such that the error is small (in fact, can this be done the actual binomial distribution?). Then, taking the derivative of the LHS with respect to $k$ by applying the envelope theorem we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial k} \max_{p}  \left\{2 \cdot\mathbb E [\min \{n-k, X\}] - n p (1+p) \right\} &= 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial k} \int_0^{n-k} 1-F_{p^*(k)}(x)dx\\ &= - 2 \cdot (1-F_{p^*(k)}(n-k))
\end{align*}
where $p^*(k)$ is the respective optimum for a given $k$. It would suffice to show that $-2 \cdot (1-F_{p^*(k)}(n-k))$ is decreasing in $k$. Is there any flaw with this reasoning?

The inequality doesn't hold for $k=n$.

@JimB I think $p=0$ does the trick

Sorry,  you are correct.  It's way past my bedtime.

I think everything you have done is valid, but there may be a simpler path.
Use the fact that $\min\{n-k, j\} \geq \frac{n-k}{n} j$ for all $j \in \{0, \dots, n\}$. This lets you obtain $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim B(n, p)}[\min\{k-n, X\}] \geq \frac{n-k}{n} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim B(n, p)}[X] = (n-k)p$. After you apply this estimate to the left of your original equation, you can find $p^*$ for this estimate and do some algebra to obtain the desired lower bound.

The maximum over $p$ of $2(n-k)p - np(1+p)$ ends up being less than $(n-k)/4$ for any $k>0$, so this bound does not work, unfortunately.
